# Flutter - Style DropdownButton and DropdownMenu on ThemeData not working

Tags: flutter

I just want to set the color of all my dropdown things inside an `AlertDialog` to white using `ThemeData`. I thought I can just do that from `ThemeData.dropdownMenuTheme`. But unfortunately nothing works so far.

This is the `ThemeData` part.

```
class Env{

  static ThemeData theme = ThemeData(
    dropdownMenuTheme : DropdownMenuThemeData(
      textStyle : TextStyle(
        color : Colors.white
      ),
      menuStyle : MenuStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll<Color>(Colors.blue),
      ),
      inputDecorationTheme : InputDecorationTheme(
        labelStyle : TextStyle(
          color : Colors.white
        ),
        enabledBorder : UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide : BorderSide(
            color : Colors.white
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder : UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide : BorderSide(
            color : Colors.white
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
  )
}
```

And this is the simplified code for `showDialog`.

```
showDialog(
  context : context,
  builder : (BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(builder : (BuildContext context, Function setState){
       return AlertDialog(
          title : Text('...'),
          content : SingleChildScrollView(child : Column(
             crossAxisAlignment : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
             children : [Row(children : [
                DropdownButton<int>(
                   value : value,
                   items : [for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) DropdownMenuItem(
                      value : i, child : Text(values[i]),
                   )],
                )
             ])]
          )),
       );
    })
  }
);
```

And this is how I set the `theme` to the `MaterialApp`.

```
MaterialApp(theme : Env.theme, home : scaffold);
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Isn't the default style for dropdown already white by default? unless this is an example

Comment: @MendelG i don't think so. by default i have grey underline and grey icon button. i want them in white

Comment: @stackunderflow Is the expected output to remove the underline?
If so, you need to use `DropdownButtonHideUnderline`

Comment: @pskink do you mean set it directly to the widget? sorry but i want to set it on the theme

Comment: ok, so I checked [dropdownMenuTheme](https://api.flutter-io.cn/flutter/material/ThemeData/dropdownMenuTheme.html) docs, they say: "A theme for customizing the appearance and layout of DropdownMenu widgets." - so it is for `DropdownMenu` and not `DropdownButton` widgets

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> By default I have grey underline and grey icon button. I want them in white

1. To remove the underline, use `DropdownButtonHideUnderline`.
2. The dropdown has an `icon` field which you can set it's color:

**Code**

```dart
  DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton(
      icon: Icon(
      Icons.arrow_drop_down,
      color: Colors.green, // <-- your color. E.g, white
),
   value: value,
```

**Result:**

[image]